# Forgot about an accident when signed up for car insurance

Tags: france, car-insurance

I have moved to France, bought a vehicle and signed up for car insurance. I said that I didn't have any car accidents over the past 2 years, but when I got my letters of experience from my previous car insurance, I saw that one of the letters listed one parking garage single-car accident in the past 2 years, about which I had forgotten. So, now...

- If I tell my new insurance company that I had forgotten about the accident, will it consider me suspicious?
- Would it be better not to have been insured in the past 2 years than to have had a single-car parking accident, from the insurance cost standpoint?

What would you do in this situation?

Comment: It might make a difference whether you were driving a car which damaged a parked car, or your car was damaged while it was parked.

Comment: Didn't the new insurance ask for the proof of history ? Was it because your previous insurance was not in France ?

Comment: @audionuma Yes, it did ask, but that's a different matter.

Comment: This isn't really an expat question. @gnasher729's answer is reasonably true all over the world, irregardless of whether you are an expat or not.

Answer (score 3):

If you tell them about the accident, they most likely will adjust your premium accordingly. If you have an accident *before* you tell them and they find out, you could be in deep trouble; that's a good reason for them not to pay or to recover the money from you.

"Would it be better not to have been insured?" I don't know, but you *were* insured, and you *had* an accident, whether you were insured or not, so do yourself a favour and don't try to hide this. The fact is that if you don't tell them, your insurance may be invalid. They will still take your money, they will still pay out third party damage to third parties, but they will ask you to pay the money back if they find out.